# Add two drop down lists with checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written java script code for one drop down list which has multiple option select with checkboxes. I want to create two such dropdown lists. I tried many ways  but it only works for one dropdown list. Below is my code with html, css and javascript.

```js
var checkList = document.getElementById(1);
var items = document.getElementById('items');
checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
  if (items.classList.contains('visible')) {
    items.classList.remove('visible');
    items.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    items.classList.add('visible');
    items.style.display = "block";
  }


}

items.onblur = function(evt) {
  items.classList.remove('visible');
}
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='1' value='1' class='dropdown-check-list' tabindex='100'>
    <span class='anchor'>Select Term(s)</span>
    <ul id='items' class='items'>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 1 </li>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 2 </li>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id='2' value='2' class='dropdown-check-list' tabindex='100'>
    <span class='anchor'>Select Term(s)</span>
    <ul id='items' class='items'>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 1 </li>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 2 </li>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

[This appears as follows. Only the first dropdown works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh5Pf.png)

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid (`items`), therefore `getElementById` will only select the first one.

Comment: Not to mention, you have two `<body>` tags... You can only have one set of `<body>` tags on a page. All content on the page (other that the items that belong in the `<head>`) must be within one single set of `<body>` tags. Most browsers are "smart" enough to correct this mistake when rendering the page, but that should absolutely never be relied upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function dropdownClick(n){
  
  var checkList = document.getElementById(n);
  var items = document.getElementById('items'+n);
  if (items.classList.contains('visible')) {
    items.classList.remove('visible');
    items.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    items.classList.add('visible');
    items.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='1' value='1' class='dropdown-check-list' tabindex='100'>
    <span class='anchor' onclick="dropdownClick(1);">Select Term(s)</span>
    <ul id='items1' class='items'>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 1 </li>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 2 </li>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id='2' value='2' class='dropdown-check-list' tabindex='100'>
    <span class='anchor' onclick="dropdownClick(2);">Select Term(s)</span>
    <ul id='items2' class='items'>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 1 </li>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 2 </li>
      <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It would be easy and more optimise  with jquery. You do not want to use jquery?

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 dropdowns, but you've selected only one dropdown by its id:

`var checkList = document.getElementById(1);`

Edit your second dropdown to this:
Add following at the end of the script tag:

```js
var checkList2 = document.getElementById(2);
var items2 = document.getElementById('items2');
checkList2.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
  if (items2.classList.contains('visible')) {
    items2.classList.remove('visible');
    items2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    items2.classList.add('visible');
    items2.style.display = "block";
  }
}

items2.onblur = function(evt) {
  items2.classList.remove('visible');
}
```

```html
<div id='2' value='2' class='dropdown-check-list' tabindex='100'>
  <span class='anchor'>Select Term(s)</span>
  <ul id='items2' class='items2'>
    <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 1 </li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 2 </li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' />Term 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**But it's not a good idea to have such a duplicated code.**

Comment: I didn't downvote but... kinda strange to give OP advice and then tell him that it's a bad idea to follow it, no?

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this using a loop?